# `onCreate` method is not getting called

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am using **Dagger2.22** to inject **MainActivity** which extends **BaseActivity** and the *BaseActivity* extends the **DaggerAppCompatActivity**. It seems like the `onCreate()` methods of both the activities are not getting called as I was calling a function inside *onCreate()* of *BaseActivity* and that wasn't working, when I put the *log* statements inside them, they are not getting printed as well and when I had put the debugger on *onStart()* and *onCreate()* of both the activities then It turns out that instead of *onCreate()* methods getting called *onStart()* method of *MainActivity* followed by *onStart()* of *BaseActivity* is getting called. Though the *MainActivity* is getting displayed and if it was created then the *onCreate()* method would have got called but no code inside *onCreate()* method seems to work neither they are getting called in debugging. I don't understand what the heck is happening?

**BaseActivity**

```java
public abstract class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = BaseActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Inject
    public SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");


    }

    private void subscribeObservers(){
        Log.d(TAG, "subscribeObservers: ");
        sessionManager.getAuthUser().observe(this, new Observer<AuthResource<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(AuthResource<User> userAuthResource) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: auth resource ==> " + userAuthResource + "auth status ==> " + userAuthResource.status);
                if (userAuthResource != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: auth status ==> " + userAuthResource.status);

                    switch (userAuthResource.status) {
                        case LOADING: {
                            break;
                        }
                        case AUTHENTICATED: {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: LOGIN SUCCESS: " + userAuthResource.data.getEmail());
                            break;
                        }
                        case ERROR: {
                            Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, userAuthResource.message +
                                            "\nDid you enter number between 1 and 10",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        }
                        case NOT_AUTHENTICATED: {
                            navLoginScreen();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void navLoginScreen(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout: {
                sessionManager.logout();
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

*This is the module that I had injected in the component*
**ActivityBuildersModule**

```java
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
            AuthViewModelsModule.class,
            AuthModule.class
    })
    abstract AuthActivity contributeAuthActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to override the other onCreate method signature ? `void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `onCreate()` to override is this:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and not what you overriden in your code.

Comment: This works. But can you explain why the signature I used is not getting called?

Comment: Because this different method

Comment: I got that. But the Android docs are not much elaborative about the distinction between the two and how they are called by the Android system. If you could provide an in-depth explanation and append that to your answer then that would be a great help.

Comment: The method above with the PersistableBundle is only called if you set the `android:persistableMode` property to `persistAcrossReboots`.